# Proof: In a topological vector space, every neighborhood of $0$ contains a balanced neighborhood of $0$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I was reading this proof in Rudin 2/e (Th 1.14), but couldn't work it out. Suppose $U$ is a neighbhorhood of $0$ in the topological vector space $X$, then

> Since scalar multiplication is continuous, there is a $\delta>0$ and there is a neighborhood $V$ of $0$ in $X$ s.t. $\alpha V\subset U$ whenever $|\alpha|<\delta$.

I know that since scalar multiplication is continuous, given any $\delta$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $0$ s.t. $\delta V \in U$. But how can I ensure that for any $|\alpha|<\delta$, $\alpha V\subset U$ still goes through? It seems I might have missed something pretty obvious, since [this document](http://www.math.pitt.edu/~hqjiang/2303/functional.pdf) gives the same argument, but I just don't seem to be able to figure out. Could anyone give a hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scalar multiplication is continuous as a map $\mathbb{K}\times E \to E$, so for every neighbourhood $U$ of $0$, there are neighbourhoods $D$ of $0$ in $\mathbb{K}$ and $V$ of $0$ in the vector space $E$ with $D\cdot V \subset U$. Every neighbourhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{K}$ contains a disk (or a symmetric interval, if we're dealing with real vector spaces), so we may assume $D$ is a disk (symmetric interval). But then $D\cdot V$ is balanced.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot that scalar multiplication is actually a map from $\mathbb{K} \times E$ to $E$.